# Canvas coming to its original position on browser resize

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I am using a move effect to move a canvas from y= 230 to y = 0. The move effect is taking place. But when I resize the browser, the canvas goes back to its original position i.e y = 230. Is there any solution for this?

```
<mx:Parallel id="expand" >

        <mx:Fade target="{rightTopCanvas}" duration="600" alphaTo="0.0" />

        <s:Move target="{rightBottomCanvas}" yTo="{rightTopCanvas.y}" duration="600"  />


        <mx:Resize target="{rightBottomCanvas}" heightTo="{containerCanvas.height}" duration="600" />

    </mx:Parallel>
```

Comment: Please Give us Sample Code that what u have tried and if possible give height and width in percentage(%) [Refer mx.containers.Canvas](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/Canvas.html)

Comment: you might have an event handler, which is setting the x and y values to its original i.e. y=230.

Comment: if you have Flash Builder, you could add a watch expression on the canvas' y property, in the debugger, to discover what triggers the change